# Windows 7 ad-hoc mode with iphone, no APIPA IP addressing on Windows 7

Tags: windows, iphone

I want my Windows 7 laptop and my iPhone to "see" each other via wireless ad-hoc mode.  My iPhone is getting the appropriate APIPA addressing (169.254.xxx.xxx), but my Windows 7 operating system is just "waiting for users".  It does not seem to know that the iPhone is a valid peer.  How do I get Windows 7 to recognize that it has established an ad-hoc network to give itself an IP address automatically via APIPA?